# DB2 how to get the not like for multiple rows from two tables

Tags: db2

I am a beginner DB2  dveloper

I have a requirement of getting the below out put by joining two tables to show the result of excluded like condition .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eum3.png)

List of fruits

```
Name       Type
----       ----
apple      fruit
cranberry  fruit
blueberry  fruit
neamleaf   leaf
lemongrass leaf
```

Filters:

```
Name       Type
----       ----
%berry     fruit
%grass     leaf
%root      vegetable
```

Filtered result, showing fruits not matching the `like` filter list

```
Name       Type
----       ----
apple      fruit
neamleaf   leaf
```

Any idea How to get it ?

Comment: Hi, you edited the question, but deleted the whole data, and the whole information, at this point, the question is not making any sense and the reaching point is unreachable. FYI- check [mcve] :)

Comment: There is no output shown.

Comment: Hi Ijust updated the question as an image ,Can you please check now

Comment: @Seeker_Strange Stavr00 made a valiant attempt at editing your image into the question, but you should really make an edit and edit the rest of the data including the attempted query and the result into the question as text rather than as an image. That helps those who want to cut and past the info into thier environment to replicate your issues. Otherwise you might have your question closed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
create table master
  (type     varchar(10),
   name     varchar(25));
insert into master
  values ('fruit', 'apple'),  
         ('fruit', 'pineapple'),
         ('fruit', 'cranberry'),
         ('fruit', 'blueberry'),
         ('fruit', 'papaya'),
         ('fruit', 'orange'),
         ('leaf', 'neamleaf'),
         ('leaf', 'lemongrass'),
         ('leaf', 'orangegrass');

create table slave
  (type     varchar(10),
   search   varchar(25));
insert into slave
  values ('fruit', 'pple'), 
         ('fruit', 'berry'),
         ('leaf', 'grass');

select m.type, m.name
  from master m
where not exists
  (select * 
     from slave s
     where s.type = m.type
       and m.name like '%' || s.search || '%');
```

It provided the following output:

```
type    name
-----   --------
fruit   papaya
fruit   orange
leaf    neamleaf
```

**Why**
Your depicted output confused me a bit, because I would not have expected your query to work in the first place. The concatenation didn't work for me (maybe that syntax is specific to LUW, but since `select` was spelled `slect`, I suspect that your example was hand keyed rather than cut and paste). When I tried your method with syntax that worked for me, I got two rows for papaya, and two rows for orange, along with one row for each of the other fruits.  This is because the join using `m.type = s.type` provides two rows for each of the fruits (one for each 'fruit' row in `slave`), then `m.name not like '%'||s.search||'%'` filters out the rows that don't match the search field in the result set.

Let's look at the unfiltered result set:

```
m.type    m.name      s.type    s.search    filtered/output
------    ----------- --------- ----------- ---------------
fruit     apple       fruit     pple        xxxx filtered
fruit     apple       fruit     berry            output
fruit     pineapple   fruit     pple        xxxx filtered
fruit     pineapple   fruit     berry            output
fruit     cranberry   fruit     pple             output 
fruit     cranberry   fruit     berry       xxxx filtered
fruit     blueberry   fruit     pple             output 
fruit     blueberry   fruit     berry       xxxx filtered
fruit     papaya      fruit     pple             output 
fruit     papaya      fruit     berry            output 
fruit     orange      fruit     pple             output 
fruit     orange      fruit     berry            output
leaf      neamleaf    leaf      grass            output 
fruit     lemongrass  leaf      grass       xxxx filtered
fruit     orangegrass leaf      grass       xxxx filtered
```

Comment: Thanks for the details this new updated query worked .